# Extract text with Java regex with reference support

Tags: java, regex

I am having some problem writing a method in Java. It basically extracts text with matching pattern and returns *ALL* the extractions. It simply works just like `java.util.regex.Matcher`'s `find()`/`matches()` then `group()` :

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileContent);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(matcher.matches()) {
    sb.append(matcher.group()).append("\n");
}
return sb.toString();
```

However, I would like the extractions to be formatted with the references(dollar sign,`$`) and literal-character-escaping (backslash,`\`) support, just like the replacement in `Matcher.replaceAll(replacement)`([Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String))). For example:

```
fileContent = """
    aaabbcac aabb
    bcbcbbccc babba
""";
pattern = Pattern.compile("bb.*(.)(abb)");
extractionFormatter = "$1: $0, \\$$2";
```

The expected output would be:

```
a: bbcac aabb, $abb
b: bbccc babb, $abb
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to do. Do you know if there is any existing library/method that can achieve this without having me to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Why don't use use `matcher.group(1)` and `.matcher.group(2)` instead?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I have attempted using `.group(n)` already, but I just don't know how to make them work for the formatter. The thing about the formatter string is that, it is provided by the user, so I have no control on how to format the extraction in advance.

Comment: Is `extractionFormatter` your own specified custom template, that you want to parse and then convert the `$1` for example to `matcher.group(1)`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird It basically is a just simple string provided by the user. It is designed to work just like the `replacement` in `Matcher.replaceAll(replacement)` . So the user can type in anything like `Hello, $1!`.

Comment: The user enters `extractionFormatter` via a JTextPane on the GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `results` method from the `Matcher` class which returns a stream of `MatchResult`s to first get all matches, get the results as string using `MatchResult.group`, replace now using the method `String.replaceAll` using the pattern as regex and your `extractionFormatter` as replacement and finally join all using new line:

```
String fileContent = "aaabbcac aabb\n" +
                     "bcbcbbccc babba";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("bb.*(.)(abb)");
String extractionFormatter = "$1: $0, \\$$2";

String output = pattern.matcher(fileContent)
                        .results()
                        .map(MatchResult::group)
                        .map(s -> s.replaceAll(pattern.pattern(), extractionFormatter))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead.

The thing to note is that if you want to get the desired output with capture groups, you would have to match (to remove) from the string that should not be there in the replacement.

Using a pattern that would give the desired output:

```
String fileContent = """
aaabbcac aabb
bcbcbbccc babba
""";
String pattern = "(?m)^.*?(bb\\S*).*(.)(abb).*$";
String extractionFormatter = "$2: $1 $2$3, \\$$3";
System.out.print(fileContent.replaceAll(pattern, extractionFormatter));
```

Output

```
a: bbcac aabb, $abb
b: bbccc babb, $abb
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/IjbqM6).

---

Or using the Stringbuilder, Matcher and the while loop:

```
String fileContent = """
aaabbcac aabb
bcbcbbccc babba
""";
String pat = "bb.*(.)(abb)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pat);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileContent);
String extractionFormatter = "$1: $0, \\$$2";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while(matcher.find()) {
    sb.append(matcher.group().replaceAll(pat, extractionFormatter)).append("\n");
}
System.out.print(sb);
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/PJQHZ9).